# Pine Scripting - Error An argument of 'series float' type was used but 'input float' is expected

Tags: pine-script-v5

I'm trying to plot horizontal line on daily 20 ema price, but getting error while doing so ' Error An argument of 'series float' type was used but 'input float' is expected'
I'm a beginner, any help is appreciated..
How to plot the same on multiple timeframes like weekly, monthly

Here is the code..

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true )
e20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
hline(e20, title = "DEMA", color = color.green, linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)
plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of daily ema changes on each bar. If we draw a line from each daily ema points to another, it would not be horizontal a line. A horizontal line must have a constant value, not a moving one.

[What I mean is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1qgv.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).